# How to implement a ListView with fastscroll and albhabet indexer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

Please help I am struck in this for 2 days.I would like to implement a ListView with fastscroll and albhabet indexer as in the contacts application/below image. I'm using a SimpleAdapter to populate the ListView. As seen from the image, by selecting a letter from the alphabet indexer at the right, the listView selection goes to the corresponding ListItem. Please share some examples. Thank u In advance.
EX: Below is my code it is just sorting the alphabet and when i onclick on E alphabet data related to E is gng to diaplay..But it is not showing E textbox in middle when i on touch of alphabet.

[image]

How to display E text box in middle..When i touch fastscroll middle text box must show.

MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,SearchView.OnCloseListener {

private ListView listView;
private SearchView search;
EfficientAdapter objectAdapter;
EfficientAdapter2 objectAdapter1;
int textlength=0;
private CheckBox checkStat, checkRoutine, checkTat;
 private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    // x and y coordinates within our side index
    private static float sideIndexX;
    private static float sideIndexY;

    // height of side index
    private int sideIndexHeight;

    // number of items in the side index
    private int indexListSize;

    // list with items for side index
    private ArrayList<Object[]> indexList = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.homempleb);
   Log.i("scan"," txtScanResult ");

   Arrays.sort(CountriesList.name);
ActionItem nextItem     = new ActionItem(); 
final QuickAction quickAction = new QuickAction(this, QuickAction.VERTICAL);
quickAction.addActionItem(nextItem);
quickAction.setOnDismissListener(new QuickAction.OnDismissListener()           {            
    @Override
    public void onDismiss() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dismissed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});


listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.homelistView);
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
objectAdapter = new EfficientAdapter(this);
 mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SideIndexGestureListener());
listView.setAdapter(objectAdapter);


}
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
        {
            return true;
        } else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Object[]> createIndex(String[] strArr)
    {
        ArrayList<Object[]> tmpIndexList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        Object[] tmpIndexItem = null;

        int tmpPos = 0;
        String tmpLetter = "";
        String currentLetter = null;
        String strItem = null;

        for (int j = 0; j < strArr.length; j++)
        {
            strItem = strArr[j];
            currentLetter = strItem.substring(0, 1);

            // every time new letters comes
            // save it to index list
            if (!currentLetter.equals(tmpLetter))
            {
                tmpIndexItem = new Object[3];
                tmpIndexItem[0] = tmpLetter;
                tmpIndexItem[1] = tmpPos - 1;
                tmpIndexItem[2] = j - 1;

                tmpLetter = currentLetter;
                tmpPos = j + 1;

                tmpIndexList.add(tmpIndexItem);
            }
        }

        // save also last letter
        tmpIndexItem = new Object[3];
        tmpIndexItem[0] = tmpLetter;
        tmpIndexItem[1] = tmpPos - 1;
        tmpIndexItem[2] = strArr.length - 1;
        tmpIndexList.add(tmpIndexItem);

        // and remove first temporary empty entry
        if (tmpIndexList != null && tmpIndexList.size() > 0)
        {
            tmpIndexList.remove(0);
        }

        return tmpIndexList;
    }
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.homelistView);
        LinearLayout sideIndex = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sideIndex);
        sideIndexHeight = sideIndex.getHeight();
        sideIndex.removeAllViews();

        // TextView for every visible item
        TextView tmpTV = null;

        // we'll create the index list
        indexList = createIndex(CountriesList.name);

        // number of items in the index List
        indexListSize = indexList.size();

        // maximal number of item, which could be displayed
        int indexMaxSize = (int) Math.floor(sideIndex.getHeight() / 20);

        int tmpIndexListSize = indexListSize;

        // handling that case when indexListSize > indexMaxSize
        while (tmpIndexListSize > indexMaxSize)
        {
            tmpIndexListSize = tmpIndexListSize / 2;
        }

        // computing delta (only a part of items will be displayed to save a
        // place)
        double delta = indexListSize / tmpIndexListSize;

        String tmpLetter = null;
        Object[] tmpIndexItem = null;

        // show every m-th letter
        for (double i = 1; i <= indexListSize; i = i + delta)
        {
            tmpIndexItem = indexList.get((int) i - 1);
            tmpLetter = tmpIndexItem[0].toString();
            tmpTV = new TextView(this);
            tmpTV.setText(tmpLetter);
            tmpTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tmpTV.setTextSize(20);
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
            tmpTV.setLayoutParams(params);
            sideIndex.addView(tmpTV);
        }

        // and set a touch listener for it
        sideIndex.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                // now you know coordinates of touch
                sideIndexX = event.getX();
                sideIndexY = event.getY();

                // and can display a proper item it country list
                displayListItem();

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    class SideIndexGestureListener extends
    GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
 {
   @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
        float distanceX, float distanceY)
{
    // we know already coordinates of first touch
    // we know as well a scroll distance
    sideIndexX = sideIndexX - distanceX;
    sideIndexY = sideIndexY - distanceY;

    // when the user scrolls within our side index
    // we can show for every position in it a proper
    // item in the country list
    if (sideIndexX >= 0 && sideIndexY >= 0)
    {
        displayListItem();
    }

    return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
}
  }

    public void displayListItem()
    {
    // compute number of pixels for every side index item
    double pixelPerIndexItem = (double) sideIndexHeight / indexListSize;

    // compute the item index for given event position belongs to
    int itemPosition = (int) (sideIndexY / pixelPerIndexItem);

    // compute minimal position for the item in the list
    int minPosition = (int) (itemPosition * pixelPerIndexItem);

    // get the item (we can do it since we know item index)
    Object[] indexItem = indexList.get(itemPosition);

    // and compute the proper item in the country list
    int indexMin = Integer.parseInt(indexItem[1].toString());
    int indexMax = Integer.parseInt(indexItem[2].toString());
    int indexDelta = Math.max(1, indexMax - indexMin);

    double pixelPerSubitem = pixelPerIndexItem / indexDelta;
    int subitemPosition = (int) (indexMin + (sideIndexY - minPosition) / pixelPerSubitem);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.homelistView);
    listView.setSelection(subitemPosition);
    }
```

EfficientAdapter.java

```
 public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;
  private Context context;

  public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
this.context=context;

  }


 public int getCount() {
return CountriesList.name.length;
 }

     public Object getItem(int position) {

return position;
 }

      public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
   }

         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.homemplebrowview, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.name);
    holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.mrn);
    holder.text3 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.date);
    holder.text4 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.age);
    holder.text5 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.gender);
    holder.text6 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.wardno);
    holder.text7 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.roomno);
    holder.text8 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.bedno);                  
    holder.btnList = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);
 //   holder.btnList.setOnClickListener(this);

    holder.btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                       
            Intent next=new Intent(context, SeviceDetails.class);
            context.startActivity(next);
        }
    });


    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.text1.setText(CountriesList.name[position]);
holder.text2.setText(CountriesList.mrn[position]);
holder.text3.setText(CountriesList.actualstart[position]);
holder.text4.setText(CountriesList.age[position]);
holder.text5.setText(CountriesList.gender[position]);
holder.text6.setText(CountriesList.wardNo[position]);
holder.text7.setText(CountriesList.roomNo[position]);
holder.text8.setText(CountriesList.bedNo[position]);

return convertView;
     }
     static class ViewHolder {
public Button btnList;
public TextView text8;
public TextView text7;
public TextView text6;
public TextView text5;
public TextView text4;
public TextView text1;
public TextView text2;
public TextView text3;
     }

  @Override
     public void notifyDataSetChanged()
  {
super.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }


    }
```

Comment: [Here is an example android project with alphabet scroll and section header.](https://github.com/amalChandran/ListviewAlphabetIndexer)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Simple Code for alphabet indexing in ListView, which uses 2 java program files

1.The MainActivity file where we handling the indexing of listview

2.The CustomAdapter.java file which is the subclass of BaseAdapter for listing the elements.

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private Map<String, Integer> mapIndex;
    private String[] fruits;
    private ListView fruitsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
        fruitsList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, Arrays.asList(fruits)));

        getIndexList(fruits);
        displayIndex();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        fruitsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_fruits);
        fruits = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruits_array);
        Arrays.sort(fruits);
    }

    private void getIndexList(String[] fruits)
    {
        mapIndex = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<fruits.length; i++)
        {
            String fruit = fruits[i];
            String index = fruit.substring(0,1);

            if(mapIndex.get(index) == null)
                mapIndex.put(index, i);
        }
    }

    private void displayIndex()
    {
        LinearLayout indexLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.side_index);
        List<String> indexList = new ArrayList<String>(mapIndex.keySet());

        TextView textView;
        for(String index : indexList)
        {
            textView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alphabetindicator, null);
            textView.setText(index);
            textView.setOnClickListener(this);
            indexLayout.addView(textView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView selectedTextView  = (TextView) v;
        fruitsList.setSelection(mapIndex.get(selectedTextView.getText()));
    }
}
```

CustomAdaper.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private List<String> listItem;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> listItem) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listItem = listItem;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.indexindicator, parent, false);
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.textView.setText(listItem.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listItem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_fruits"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/side_index"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

alphabetIndicator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/side_list_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

IndexIndicator.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, Include a string array in strings.xml file (Replace / Increase the item based on your needs)

```
<string-array name="fruits_array">
        <item>Cantalope</item>
        <item>Date</item>
        <item>Grape</item>
        <item>Gooseberry</item>
        <item>Guava</item>
        <item>Honeydew melon</item>
        <item>Elderberry</item>
        <item>Fig</item>
        <item>Grapefruit</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is really simple to do. Here is how I've done it in my app. You can add your proper parameters, it is simple and easy to understand.

// charsContainer is a linear layout which contains all your characters that you will touch on. They fit automatically in the linear layout so they are all visible because of the weight value you associate on chars TextView later

```
final LinearLayout charsContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.charsContainer);

// alphabetical_index is a framelayout which contains charsContainer and alphabetical_index_indicator, this is for the indicator to be visible over selected character.

final FrameLayout alphabetical_index = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.alphabetical_index);

// alphabetical_index_indicator is an image displayed when your finger touches a character and move up and down 

final ImageView alphabetical_index_indicator = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.alphabetical_index_indicator);

for (int i = 0; i < chars.size() ; i++) {

    TextView charTextView = new TextView(this);
    charTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 1));
    charTextView.setText(chars.get(i).toString());
    charTextView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    charTextView.setTextSize(11);
    charTextView.setPadding(convertValueToDP(4), 0, convertValueToDP(4), 0);
    charsContainer.addView(charTextView);


}

alphabetical_index.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int alphabetical_index_top = (int) alphabetical_index.getTop();
        int alphabetical_index_bottom = (int) alphabetical_index.getBottom();

        boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
        boolean hasHomeKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);

        if(hasBackKey || hasHomeKey){
            alphabetical_index_bottom = ((int) alphabetical_index.getY()) + alphabetical_index.getHeight();
        }else{
            alphabetical_index_bottom = ((int) alphabetical_index.getY()) + alphabetical_index.getHeight() - convertValueToDP(36);
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                // Do
                getListView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                if(alphabetical_index_indicator.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                    alphabetical_index_indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    getListView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyActivity.this, R.anim.fadein);
                    alphabetical_index_indicator.startAnimation(anim);
                }

                if (y > alphabetical_index_top && (y - charsContainer.getChildAt(0).getHeight()) > alphabetical_index_top && y < alphabetical_index_bottom) {
                    alphabetical_index_indicator.setY(y - charsContainer.getChildAt(0).getHeight());
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < charsContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {

                    View child = charsContainer.getChildAt(i);

                    if (y > child.getTop() && y < child.getBottom()) {

                        Character character = ((TextView) child).getText().toString().charAt(0);

                        for (int j = 0; i < listViewStringArray.size(); j++) {
                            if (listViewStringArray.get(j).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()).charAt(0) == character) {
                                getListView().setSelection(j);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

                // Do
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                // Do
                getListView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyActivity.this,R.anim.fadeout);
                anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        alphabetical_index_indicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        getListView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                alphabetical_index_indicator.startAnimation(anim);

                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});


public static int convertValueToDP(float dp){

    DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return (int)px;
}
```